# Tableau remove duplicates based on a condition

Tags: database, tableau-api

I am trying to remove duplicates from the Ticket field in my database but I want to remove the duplicates that have older dates. example,

Ticket | Date

MG17000 | 1/1/2017

MG17000 | 1/1/2018

MG17010 | 1/1/2018

so I want the answer to be

MG17000 | 1/1/2018

MG17010 | 1/1/2018

I used **countd(Ticket)** but it does not remove the right tickets(it removes the ticket that corresponds to 1/1/2018 instead of 1/1/2017). any suggestions on how to perform this task.

Thanks!

Comment: Use the max function on your date column.

Comment: when I use max date ti would only show the total number of tickets which in this case is 2 after removing the duplicates. instead i want to be able to see the date as well as the total     DATEPART('day', MAX([Date-Created])) on the column and on the rows I have countd(ticket)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Create formula `[Rank - Date]` with below code:

```
RANK_UNIQUE((MAX(SPLIT([database field],'|',2))))
//This will create a values for every ticket
```

Now one more formula to filter only date with max value and drag to filter and select `True`

```
[Rank - Date]=1
```

You should be able to get required data

Comment: I get null when creating a calculated field RANK_UNIQUE((MAX(SPLIT([Ticket],'|',2)))). Ticket is string in my analysis

Answer (score 0):

Use a level-of-detail (LOD) calculation. Create the calculation with this formula and it will give you the number of records per ticket, regardless of what dimensions you have on rows and shelves.

```
{FIXED [ticket] : count([date])}
```

If you have any date filtering and you want the calculation to count tickets outside the date filter range, switch `FIXED` to `INCLUDE`.
Drag that as one of you measures. Then use the max([date]) to show the most recent date.

From the sample data you showed in the question, you will see something like

> MG17000 1/1/2018   2
>
> MG17010 1/1/2018   1

Comment: but LOD will not show other tickets of the same day. it will not show 1/1/2018   MG17000          1/1/2018      MG17001. those have different ticket numbers but would count as 1

Comment: Your question is not very clear on what you want to accomplish. Your question text says nothing about counting tickets, just that you want to remove duplicates. Specifically, in your question you gave an example of what you want the answer to be and that example has only a ticket number and the most recent date. If you need to edit your question to include more requirements, click the edit button to refine your requirements. I'm having to deduce what you want based on comments you are making on the answers we are providing for you.